# Usernames are displayed for questions on the main page, but no Action is displayed

Tags: feature-request, display-names

On any given question the last person to add something to the question, be it ask, edit or answer it, is displayed(on the main page).

> 1m ago TsSkTo 96

This, however, doesn't show what I did. So if someone comes along and edits it it would show their name and how long ago. Which can be confusing if one assumes the name assosiated with the question is the asker.

But even if the person with the last action on the question is displayed, shouldn't it be something like this?

> *Asked by:* TsSkTo 96 1m ago

and then

> *Edited by:* [moderator] 500k 25s ago

The Idea here being to add a field explaining what was the last *action* applied to the question along with who did it.

The Duplicate question shows the same problem, that being:

*The last user to modify or add to the question is displayed on the list, along with the time stamp. It does not, however say what he or she did to the question, that is unless you click the time stamp and inspect the post.*

In the previous question it was suggested that the original poster *always* be the one displayed on the question. That is flawed, I understand that the latest user to add to the question should be displayed in order to show when the question was last active. If one goes on to read the comments, the fact that there is no "Modified by" in the main list is mentioned and proposed as a good idea by the moderator answering the question. The last comment suggests the exact same thing.

The is the idea of this post is to provide and implement the solution that the "duplicate" post was unable to. The problem is still there. It *is* ambiguous what the person displayed has done to the question. Why not provide that information on the list?

Comment: FYI: If you click the "1m ago" part, it'll link directly to the post they affected, meaning you can instantly spot whether they made that post, or just edited it.

Comment: @Bart that question points out the same problem. The feature I am suggesting be added is the *action* display. So we know, without folowing any links, what was the last action applied to the question; not just who tinkered with it.

Comment: @TsSkTo That question also goes on to request that both names should be shown.

Comment: @Bart That would be useless. If a question has ten answers and five edits do you want to show fifteen names? SO displays the name associated with the last action so we can know when the question was last active. I'm just proposing we add a field that says what happened to the question when it was last active. That wouldn't take much space and would provide useful, at a glance, information.

Comment: @Bart please take another look at the question, I still believe that is a necessary feature that can be added